# How to efficiently delete the first N characters in each line in a paragraph without using visual mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, is it possible to delete the first N characters in each line in a paragraph without using visual mode or using dot command multiple times?

Convert

```
www.some_website.com
www.some_webiste2.com
```

to

```
some_website.com
some_webiste2.com
```

Without using visual mode or `d4l` `j` `.`?

I guess my question can be also phrased as "is there a linewise operator for a paragraph text object?"

Comment: Vim's substitute command? Example: `:%s/^....//` to remove the first four characters of each line.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid visual mode? The obvious method is using visual block mode to delete all of that stuff in a single command.

Answer (score 3):

Executing a substitution on a range of lines is probably the most "Vim-like" solution.

Assuming you want to work on what Vim considers a *paragraph*:

```
:'{,'}s/^www\.
```

If you like counting characters:

```
:'{,'}s/.\{4}
```

One could use `:normal`too:

```
:'{,'}norm! 4x
```

See `:help navigation`, `:help :normal`, `:help \{`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `substitute` and directly using `normal` command mentioned on another answer, you could also repeat a normal command (as `d4l`) in any number of lines using the `:global` command:

```
:g/^www/normal d4l
```

Explanation:

- `:g/<patter>/` - execute on any line that matches `<pattern>` - `.` will match all non-empty lines, `^www\.` would match only those starting with urls
- `normal d4l` - execute `d4l` in normal mode